# Move content of a folder using shutil

Tags: python, directory, move, shutil

I am trying to move the content of a folder to another in Python using shtutil but it's not working as I expected.

```
dest_dir = shutil.move(str(source_directory), str(dest_dir))
return dest_dir
```

Let's say that my source directory is home/abc and my destiny directory is home/qwerty.

The final result is that the content is moved to home/querty/abc.

Is there any way of only moving the content of the directory?

### output

```
--querty
  --abc
    --dir1
    --dir 2
```

### Expected output

```
-- querty
 --dir1
 --dir2
```

Comment: Sorry, your question is not fully clear. What is the output you would like to achieve? "the content is moved to home/querty/abc" that is what normally happens. What do you expect instead?

Comment: I expected the content to be moved to home/querty

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over all the files. You can use `os.listdir` to do so.

```
import os, shutil

source = './source_dir'
dest = './dest_dir'

for file in os.listdir(source):
    src = f'{source}/{file}'
    dst = f'{dest}/{file}'
    shutil.move(src, dst)
```

This will move all the files (recursively) from `source` to `dest`.